# How to move multiple sheets to new Excel and replace words from all tabs in VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba

I tried below code to move all sheets from one Excel to another Excel (ouput.xlsx) but now I want to remove "Test" word from all tab.Formulae in all tab taking reference of Test.xlsx.

I am saving current file as Test.xlsx and then transferring all tab from Test.xlsx to Output.xlsx

```
Sub Openandmove ()
Folderpath = ThisWorkbook.Path
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks.Open (FolderPath & "WP.xlsx")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs"Test.xlsx"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wbEstimate As Workbook
Set wbEstimate = ActiveWorkbook
Dim wsList As Worksheet
Dim wbtest As Workbook
Dim numSheets = wbEstimate.Sheets.Count
Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(numsheets)).Name="list"
Dim i as Integer 
i=1

For Each Sheet in wbEstimate.Worksheets
    wslist.Cells(i,1) = Sheets.Name
    i=i+1
Next

Set wbtest = Workbook.Add
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename :=FolderPath & "\output.xlsx",FileFormat:xlOpenXMLWorkbook

For Each Sheet in wbEstimate.Sheets
   Sheet.Copy after : = wbTest.Sheets (wbTest.Sheets.Count)
Next

ActiveWorkbook.Save

Windows("output.xlsx).close
```

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to do. If you need a copy of `WP.xlsx` as `Test.xlsx`, you can use `SaveCopyAs`. Either way, just `SaveAs output.xlsx` and add and process the worksheet to contain the list of names of all sheets. Adding hyperlinks would also be useful. The issue you're having with the wrong references is avoided either by saving `As` or by copying all sheets at once (e.g. `wbEstimate.Sheets.Copy: Set wbTest = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)`). Please share more information.

Comment: My requirement is i cant use old file,it should be created new.I am trying to create new excel and want to move all tab from old file to newly created file. but after moving sheets formulae take old file reference so want o remove that file reference by replacing word("Test","")

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Workbook Adding a List of Its Worksheets

[image]

```vb
Sub CopyWithSheetList()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const SRC_NAME As String = "WP.xlsx"
    Const DST_NAME As String = "Output.xlsx"
    Const DST_LIST_SHEET_NAME As String = "List"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "A1"
    
    ' Store the folder path of the workbook containing this code, appending
    ' the path separator, in a variable.
    
    Dim FolderPath As String:
    FolderPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Open the source workbook and save it as the destination workbook.
    
    Dim wb As Workbook:
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & SRC_NAME)
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
        wb.SaveAs Filename:=FolderPath & DST_NAME, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    ' Add the list sheet.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet:
    Set dws = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)) ' last
    ' or:
    'Set dws = wb.Sheets.Add(Before:=wb.Sheets(1)) ' first
    dws.Name = DST_LIST_SHEET_NAME
    
    ' Write the list.
    
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS)
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet, r As Long
    
    For Each sws In wb.Worksheets
        If sws.Name <> DST_LIST_SHEET_NAME Then ' exclude list sheet
            r = r + 1
            dCell.Value = r
            dCell.Offset(, 1).Value = sws.Name
            Set dCell = dCell.Offset(1) ' next cell (row)
        End If
    Next sws
    
    ' Save and close.
    
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Copy with sheet list created.", vbInformation
     
End Sub
```